# pthread_join - multiple threads waiting

Tags: c++, multithreading, posix

Using POSIX threads & C++, I have an "Insert operation" which can only be done safely one at a time.

If I have multiple threads waiting to insert using pthread_join then spawning a new thread 
when it finishes. Will they all receive the "thread complete" signal at once and spawn multiple inserts or is it safe to assume that the thread that receives the "thread complete" signal first will spawn a new thread blocking the others from creating new threads.

```
/* --- GLOBAL --- */
pthread_t insertThread;



/* --- DIFFERENT THREADS --- */
// Wait for Current insert to finish
pthread_join(insertThread, NULL); 

// Done start a new one
pthread_create(&insertThread, NULL, Insert, Data);
```

---

Thank you for the replies

The program is basically a huge hash table which takes requests from clients through Sockets.

Each new client connection spawns a new thread from which it can then perform multiple operations, specifically lookups or inserts. lookups can be conducted in parallel. But inserts need to be "re-combined" into a single thread. You could say that lookup operations could be done without spawning a new thread for the client, however they can take a while causing the server to lock, dropping new requests. The design tries to minimize system calls and thread creation as much as possible.

But now that i know it's not safe the way i first thought I should be able to cobble something together

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [opengroup.org on pthread_join](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_join.html):

> The results of multiple simultaneous calls to pthread_join() specifying the same target thread are undefined.

So, you really should not have several threads joining your previous insertThread.

First, as you use C++, I recommend [boost.thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/thread.html).  They resemble the POSIX model of threads, and also work on Windows.  And it helps you with C++, i.e. by making function-objects usable more easily.

Second, why do you want to start a new thread for inserting an element, when you always have to wait for the previous one to finish before you start the next one?  Seems not to be classical use of multiple-threads.

Although... One classical solution to this would be to have one worker-thread getting jobs from an event-queue, and other threads posting the operation onto the event-queue.

If you really just want to keep it more or less the way you have it now, you'd have to do this:

- Create a condition variable, like `insert_finished`.
- All the threads which want to do an insert, wait on the condition variable.
- As soon as one thread is done with its insertion, it fires the condition variable.
- As the condition variable requires a mutex, you can just notify *all* waiting threads, they all want start inserting, but as only one thread can acquire the mutex at a time, all threads will do the insert sequentially.

But you should take care that your synchronization is not implemented in a too ad-hoc way.  As this is called `insert`, I suspect you want to manipulate a data-structure, so you probably want to implement a thread-safe data-structure first, instead of sharing the synchronization between data-structure-accesses and all clients.  I also suspect that there will be more operations then just `insert`, which will need proper synchronization...

Answer (score 2):

According to the Single Unix Specifcation: "The results of multiple simultaneous calls to pthread_join() specifying the same target thread are undefined."

The "normal way" of achieving a single thread to get the task would be to set up a condition variable (don't forget the related mutex): idle threads wait in pthread_cond_wait() (or pthread_cond_timedwait()), and when the thread doing the work has finished, it wakes up one of the idle ones with pthread_cond_signal().

Answer (score 1):

Yes as most people recommended the best way seems to have a worker thread reading from a queue. Some code snippets below

```
    pthread_t       insertThread = NULL;
    pthread_mutex_t insertConditionNewMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_mutex_t insertConditionDoneMutex    = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_cond_t  insertConditionNew      = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_cond_t  insertConditionDone     = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

       //Thread for new incoming connection
        void * newBatchInsert()
        {
           for(each Word)
           {
                            //Push It into the queue
                            pthread_mutex_lock(&lexicon[newPendingWord->length - 1]->insertQueueMutex);
                                lexicon[newPendingWord->length - 1]->insertQueue.push(newPendingWord);
                            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lexicon[newPendingWord->length - 1]->insertQueueMutex);

           }

                    //Send signal to worker Thread
                    pthread_mutex_lock(&insertConditionNewMutex);
                        pthread_cond_signal(&insertConditionNew);
                    pthread_mutex_unlock(&insertConditionNewMutex);

                    //Wait Until it's finished
                    pthread_cond_wait(&insertConditionDone, &insertConditionDoneMutex);

        }


            //Worker thread
            void * insertWorker(void *)
            {

                while(1)        
                {

                    pthread_cond_wait(&insertConditionNew, &insertConditionNewMutex);

                    for (int ii = 0; ii < maxWordLength; ++ii)
                    {                   
                            while (!lexicon[ii]->insertQueue.empty())
                            {

                                queueNode * newPendingWord = lexicon[ii]->insertQueue.front();


                                lexicon[ii]->insert(newPendingWord->word);

                                pthread_mutex_lock(&lexicon[ii]->insertQueueMutex);
                                lexicon[ii]->insertQueue.pop();
                                pthread_mutex_unlock(&lexicon[ii]->insertQueueMutex);

                            }

                    }

                    //Send signal that it's done
                    pthread_mutex_lock(&insertConditionDoneMutex);
                        pthread_cond_broadcast(&insertConditionDone);
                    pthread_mutex_unlock(&insertConditionDoneMutex);

                }

            }

            int main(int argc, char * const argv[]) 
            {

                pthread_create(&insertThread, NULL, &insertWorker, NULL);


                lexiconServer = new server(serverPort, (void *) newBatchInsert);

                return 0;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The others have already pointed out this has undefined behaviour. I'd just add that the really simplest way to accomplish your task (to allow only one thread executing part of code) is to use a simple mutex - you need the threads executing that code to be MUTally EXclusive, and that's where mutex came to its name :-)

If you need the code to be ran in a specific thread (like Java AWT), then you need conditional variables. However, you should think twice whether this solution actually pays off. Imagine, how many context switches you need if you call your "Insert operation" 10000 times per second.

Answer (score 0):

As you just now mentioned you're using a hash-table with several look-ups parallel to insertions, I'd recommend to check whether you can use a concurrent hash-table.

As the exact look-up results are non-deterministic when you're inserting elements simultaneously, such a concurrent hash-map may be exactly what you need.  I do not have used concurrent hash-tables in C++, though, but as they are available in Java, you'll for sure find a library doing this in C++.

Answer (score 0):

The only library which i found which supports inserts without locking new lookups - [Sunrise DD](http://www.sunrisetel.net/software/devtools/sunrise-data-dictionary.shtml) (And i'm not sure whether it supports concurrent inserts)

However the switch from Google's [Sparse Hash map](http://goog-sparsehash.sourceforge.net/) more than doubles the memory usage. Lookups should happen fairly infrequently so rather than trying and write my own library 
which combines the advantages of both i would rather just lock the table suspending lookups while changes are made safely.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you want to serialise inserts to the hashtable.

For this you want a lock - not spawning new threads.

Answer (score 0):

From your description that looks very inefficient as you are re-creating the insert thread every time you want to insert something. The cost of creating the thread is not 0.

A more common solution to this problem is to spawn an insert thread that waits on a queue (ie sits in a loop sleeping while the loop is empty). Other threads then add work items to the queue. The insert thread picks items of the queue in the order they were added (or by priority if you want) and does the appropriate action.

All you have to do is make sure addition to the queue is protected so that only one thread at a time has accesses to modifying the actual queue, and that the insert thread does not do a busy wait but rather sleeps when nothing is in the queue (see condition variable).

Answer (score 0):

Ideally,you dont want multiple threadpools in a single process, even if they perform different operations. The resuability of a thread is an important architectural definition, which leads to pthread_join being created in a main thread if you use C.

Ofcourse, for a C++ threadpool aka ThreadFactory , the idea is to keep the thread primitives abstract so, it can handle any of function/operation types passed to it.

A typical example would be a webserver which will have connection pools and thread pools which service connections and then process them further, but, all are derived from a common threadpool process.

SUMMARY : AVOID PTHREAD_JOIN IN any place other than a main thread.